# How to optimize this piece of AS3 code?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I am making a game for android in flash AIR with as3, and in one level my character has to collect 9 coins. The problem is that I use hitTest and if it's true, I change the y position of 2 gate doors, and that causes lag, that door movement. This is the code I use

```
if (coin1.hitTestObject(heroj)) {
        sndcoin.play();
        coin1.y=-100;
        opengate();
    }
```

and in opentgate() function I made

```
gatedoor1.y+=4;
gatedoor2.y-=4;
```

and this causes a 0.3-0.5 seconds lag for every coin collect, is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Nothing in what you've provided hints at lowering performance - are those two lines *all* that `opengate()` does?

Comment: This is just a guess but have you tried disabling sndcoin.play(); to see if that it the piece of code that is slowing things down. If that is the case you may want to lower the sound quality or compression ratio so it does not use as much cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Coin is very primitive object, hit test could be calculated as distance. If hero is close enough to the coin, you could consider it as hit.

```
var dx: Number = heroj.x - coin1.x;
var dy: Number = heroj.y - coin1.y;
const coinRadius: int = 5;

if(dx*dx + dy*dy <= coinRadius*coinRadius ){
    trace("Hero is catched coin");
}
```

Second moment, after successful hit test, free up resources, don't check for hit test again.

Comment: You can avoid the Math.sqrt a²+b²=c²
`if( dx*dx + dy*dy <= coinRadius*coinRadius ){`

Comment: Yes, without statics it will be even faster.

Comment: Just use hitTestObject, like Nicolas said, coins are pretty primitive and a rough hitTest collision handler won't hurt anyone.